# C# Last DataGridView Row Value in Textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I have a DataGridView (bound to an SQL Database Table) with a column name "order_ID". What I want is to add the last filled value in that column in the GridView/SQL Table to be shown in a textbox. How would I go about doing that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your effort first.. Plesae read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Why do you mean of "last"? Whithout some sorting in place, it has no meaning, because SQL Server enforces no particular ordering.

Comment: I've searched a lot of pages but the only solutions I could find were to show the selected row in the textbox. I have some idea of how to go about it but I don't know the code for it.

Comment: What I'm doing is adding an order to one table. It's order_ID (auto increment) is automatically generated when I enter the "date" and "grandtotal". What I want is the order_ID of the latest order I added to be displayed in a textbox? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
int lastRow = yourDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
object last_order_ID = yourDataGridView.Rows[lastRow].Cells["order_ID"].Value;
yourTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(last_order_ID);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

next id :

```
int lastRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;
        int last_order_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[lastRow].Cells["s_id"].Value) + 1;
        txt_num.Text = Convert.ToString(last_order_ID);
```